# Error: Type[CLASS_NAME] has no attribute "__dataclass_fields__"

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, type-hinting

```
@dataclass
class SUDO:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        return cls.__dataclass_fields__

def some_function(skeleton: Type[SUDO]):
    skeleton.foo()
```

This works in runtime however when I run typecheck for it keeps giving me an error complaining that `Type[SUDO]` has no attribute `__dataclass_fields__`

I'm sure that the way I'm doing this isn't proper, any suggestions?

Comment: This is probably a bug with whatever type-checker you're using. (I'm guessing mypy?) Dataclasses are pretty new, and type-checker support for them tends to still have a few rough edges imo. I'd try filing a bug report on the relevant issue tracker.